# Sum up column based on two dates in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to sum a column if it falls between two dates and based on a jobid. I'm using the below function but I keep zero as the sum value.

```
def jobrun (row):
return table1[(table1.job == row['job']) & \
        (table1.date >= row['past']) & \
        (table1.date < row['present'])]['Hours'].sum()

table2['Usage'] = table2.apply(lambda row: jobrun(row), axis = 1)
```

all the date columns are converted to `<datecolumn>.astype('datetime64').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

Please let me know what I missing.

[image]

[image]

```
Table1      
Job Hours   Date
706010  2.935   01/03/20
706010  14.9936 02/03/20
706010  14.9079 03/03/20
706010  11.1339 04/03/20
706010  0.0172  06/03/20
706010  0.0172  07/03/20
706011  0.0175  10/03/20
706011  0.0508  14/03/20
706011  0.085   16/03/20
706011  0.0347  17/03/20
706011  0.0078  18/03/20
706011  0.0169  30/03/20
706011  0.0006  01/04/20
706011  0.0172  04/04/20
706011  2.642   05/04/20
706011  6.5853  06/04/20
706011  0.2653  07/04/20
706011  0.0175  08/04/20
706012  0.0375  09/04/20
706012  0.0339  12/04/20
706012  0.0169  13/04/20
706012  0.0167  15/04/20
706012  0.1169  20/04/20
706012  0.3003  21/04/20
706012  0.0169  26/04/20
706012  6.7994  30/10/19



Table2          
Job past    present 
706010  31/07/2019  2020-04-05  
706011  31/11/2019  2020-05-05  
706012  31/07/2019  2020-05-05  


Expected Output         
Job past    present Usage
706010  31/07/2019  2020-04-05  44
706011  31/11/2019  2020-05-05  9
706012  31/07/2019  2020-05-05  7
```

Comment: It's better if you include a sample of your actual data instead of including the pictures.

Comment: Data added instead of images.

Comment: Here's a novice approach. Join the dataframes on `jobid` and retain the records that are within the range. `(Table1['Date'] >= Table2['past']) & (Table1['Date'] <= Table2['present'])`. The resulting dataframe can be used to sum up the `hours` at `jobid`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can apply `jobrun` on two dataframes, because it will give you error as `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`. (as mentioned in one of the comments)

What you might try is to perform a outer merge of `table1` and `row` based on column `job`, then modify `jobrun`, and apply it to the entire merged dataframe `df1`:

```
df1=table1.merge(row,left_on='job',right_on='job',how='outer')
def jobrun (df):
    df_out=df[(df.date >= df['past']) & \
        (df.date < df['present'])]
    df_out['Usage']=df_out['Hours'].sum()
    return df_out
jobrun(df1)
```